# Setting Array in ReactJS w/ Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I currently have an array of FooBar objects

```
interface FooBar {
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
    correct: string,
    other: string[]
}
const [arrOfObj, setArrOfObj] = useState<FooBar[]>([
        { "foo": "foolicious ", "bar": "barlicious", "correct": "foobarlicious", "other": ["oof", "f00", "rab", "r@b"]},
]);
const [shuffledArrOfObj, setShuffledArrOfObj] = useState<FooBar[]>([
        { "foo": "", "bar": "", "correct": "", "other": [""]},
]);
```

However I want to randomly shuffle the "other" array in each object so I have a shuffle function:

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const act = await shuffleObjs();
            setShuffledArrOfObj([...act]);
        })();

}, [arrOfObj]);

const shuffleObjs = () => {
      let holdArr = [...arrOfObj];
      for (let i: number = 0; i < holdArr.length; i++) {
            holdArr[i].other = await handleShuffle(holdArr[i].other);
        }
}

const handleShuffle = async (array: string[]) => {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }

        return array;
}
```

However, if I console.log(holdArr) at the end of the "shuffleObjs" function, the array of objects is totally different than the array of objects stored in the shuffledArryObj state.

Am I setting the array state the wrong way, or is there something I am missing?

EDIT: Typo wasn't the problem, it's still not working correctly. I also tried adding arrOfObj to the dep array.

Comment: Try passing `shuffledArrOfObj` to the dependency array

Comment: Where is hold[i] array that your are passing to handleShuffle(). Shouldn't it be holdArr[i]

Comment: I tried adding shuffleObjs to dep array and it caused a repetitive and infinite rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two things:

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const act = await shuffleObjs();
            setShuffledArrOfObj([...act]);
        })();

}, [arrOfObj]); //<-- Add arrOfObj to dependency Array

const shuffleObjs = () => {
      let holdArr = [...arrOfObj];
      for (let i: number = 0; i < holdArr.length; i++) {
            holdArr[i].other = await handleShuffle(hold[i].other); //<-- change hold[i] to holdArr[i]
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your fixes, the final array is now the "same" object repeated multiple times, as in the array is shuffled, but the elements are in the same order for all the arrays that have the same values for foo, bar, and correct.